# How do I use ucanaccess to access a remote server for a java interface / how do I find my remote SQL Server file path?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ucanaccess

I know that the code below works for a Microsoft Access Database but I need to switch it to my remote SQL server.

```
try {
    String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://???SQLSERVERPATH???");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

So where do I figure out what the server path is ?

Answer (score 0):

The UCanAccess JDBC driver is only designed to work with data stored in Microsoft Access datbase files (.accdb, .mdb). It cannot be used to work with data in a SQL Server database. You will need to use a SQL Server JDBC driver for that (e.g., [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)).

Comment: Java 8 does not support SQL Server JDBC Driver anymore. Any ideas on what to do ? @Gord Thompson

Comment: @SQLUser - I believe you are confusing the JDBC-ODBC Bridge (which was indeed dropped from Java 8) with a proper JDBC driver for SQL Server (see the link in the answer).